# Add Package QT to LispWorks

Tags: qt, user-interface, common-lisp, lispworks

I have trouble with commonQT.
https://github.com/commonqt/commonqt/blob/master/tutorial/conv.lisp On this page is some tutorial code, when I want compile it I get message "Package QT not found". I have no idea, when I can find Package QT.

Comment: The package should come with the library. Did you install it manually or with quicklisp?

Comment: I didnt instal anything.

Comment: You should follow the installation instructions (including the dependencies) on the [projects website](https://common-lisp.net/project/commonqt/)

Comment: So you are trying to use an external library called CommonQT, but you did not even try to install it? That sounds strange.

Comment: I loaded to quicklisp.lisp to listener, then press Enter, then create new editor copy code from github and still package QT not found

Comment: You need to install quicklisp according to [its instructions](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/). Then install the [dependencies for commonQT](https://common-lisp.net/project/commonqt/#cpp-dependecies) (possibly using [qt-libs](https://github.com/Shinmera/qt-libs)). Then install commonQT itself with `(ql:quickload :qt)`. Then try running the examples.

Comment: Yes now i can compile example code. But i have another question. What i have write to listener? (main windows) doesent work